# How to avoid explicit assignments to 'undefined' when using a generic type equal to 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following example, we have an interface with a generic type T.

If I try to use the interface with `T=undefined`, TypeScript still requires me to specify the fields that can only be of type `undefined`:

```js
interface Options<T> {
  a: T;
  b: T;
}

function execute<T>(options: Options<T>): void {
  // do something
}

execute<undefined>({ a: undefined, b: undefined });  // no error
execute<undefined>({});  // compile error: missing 'a' and 'b'
```

This seems rather too strict and counter-intuitive, as for most purposes, not specifying a value is the same as specifying a value of undefined.

Is there any way to re-write the above, so that users of `Options<T>` with `T=undefined` do not have to explicitly write `{a: undefined, b: undefined}` and just write `{}`?

Comment: Is your use case really that people will manually specify the type argument to `execute()`?  You don't need or care about inference?  Given your question *as asked*, you could rewrite to [this form](https://tsplay.dev/NaDpnw), but I'm wondering if that actually works for your underlying use case.  Let me know; I could write up an answer if that works for you, otherwise could you [edit] to show more details of your use case?

Comment: I see that you answered your own question without responding to this above comment.  Could you please review [the approach I suggested there](https://tsplay.dev/NaDpnw) and let me know whether or not it meets your needs?

Comment: The approach works until we add a 3rd property that isn't T. The problem is that once T=undefined, all the fields become optional, even those that aren't T.

Comment: Ah, you might want to [edit] the question to demonstrate that use case.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated based on feedback from comments): To make all undefined properties optional we can do the following:

```js
type OptionalUndefineds<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends undefined ? never : K]: T[K];
} & Partial<T>
```

This allows the following:

```js
type OptionalUndefineds<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends undefined ? never : K]: T[K];
} & Partial<T>

interface Options<T> {
  a: T;
  b: T;
}

function execute<T>(options: OptionalUndefineds<Options<T>>): void {
  // do something
}

execute<undefined>({ a: undefined, b: undefined });  // no error
execute<undefined>({});  // no error either
execute<number>({ a: 5, b: 3}); // no error
execute<number>({}); // error, which is correct, need numbers for a and b
```

Update (from comments): this is a better answer, it solves the last example from the list:

```js
type NullablePropsAreOptional<T> =
    (Partial<T> & { [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K] }) extends infer U ?
    { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;

function execute<T>(options: NullablePropsAreOptional<Options<T>>): void { }
execute<undefined>({ a: undefined, b: undefined, c: 2 }); // okay
execute<undefined>({ c: 2 }); // okay
execute<string>({ c: 2 }) // error
execute<string>({ a: "", b: "", c: 2 }); // okay
execute<string | undefined>({ a: "", c: 2 }); // okay
```

Update 2: ended up using the following:

```js
export type UndefinedPropsAreOptional<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K]? never : K]: T[K];
} & Partial<T>;
```

Comment: I don't quite see how this answers your question; presumably you should be showing how to use this with `execute()`, and what happens when `T` is something like `string | undefined` doesn't look desirable, [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mpxK6m).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I updated the answer to show how it applies to the example in the question

Comment: I probably won't bother writing an answer to the question, but you might want to switch `T[K] extends undefined` to `undefined extends T[K]` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nd8ynN) since presumably unions with `undefined` should also make things optional.